# How can I convert a snakecased hash into camelcase in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, formatting, interop

I'm very used to work with a javascript that connects to a rails backend and most of the time one of them has to budge to accept the others formatting rules i.e. snake_case for ruby and camelCase for javascript.

There are several methods to replace strings between this two formats, but it would be better to consider the deep replacement of all keys in a hash in a more direct way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm giving the method it worked out for me, in Cofeescript, if you need the javascript version of it you can convert it in [Coffescript site](http://coffeescript.org/).

```
class Converter

  convertString: (string)->
    #Switch to the needed format
    string.replace(/(\_[a-z])/g, ($1)-> $1.toUpperCase().replace('_',''))

  convertObject: (obj)->
    newObj = {}
    for k,v of obj
      val = if typeof v is "object" and not Array.isArray(v) then @camelizeObject(v) else v
      key = @camelizeString(k)
      newObj[key] = val
    newObj
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not against using external lib, lodash has a function for that: https://lodash.com/docs#snakeCase And it also has a bunch of useful helpers for manipulating arrays/collections/strings in Javascript.

For example, using [mapKeys](https://lodash.com/docs#mapKeys), you can "convert" your object's keys to snake_case easily:

```
var obj = {
    fooBar: 'foo',
    Bar_Foo: 'bar'
}
obj = _.mapKeys(obj, function (value, key) {
    return _.snakeCase(key);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));

/* output:
{
    "foo_bar": "foo",
    "bar_foo": "bar"
}
*/
```